# How to make this array with link-list?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

I want to draw a diagram in tikz or without tikz (image of a diagram given below). I have been able to do to some extent using texstack exchange previous questions but not able to modify it to make it work for me.

See the code and the image:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\tikzset{
node of list/.style = { 
             draw, 
             fill=orange!20, 
             minimum height=6mm, 
             minimum width=6mm,
             node distance=6mm
   },
link/.style = {
     -stealth,
     shorten >=1pt
     },
array element/.style = {
    draw, fill=white,
    minimum width = 6mm,
    minimum height = 10mm
  }
}

\def\LinkedList#1{%
  \foreach \element in \list {
     \node[node of list, right = of aux, name=ele] {\element};
     \draw[link] (aux) -- (ele);
     \coordinate (aux) at (ele.east);
  } 
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \index/\list in {1/{a,b,null}, 2/{c,null}, 3/{d,null}} {
   \node[array element] (aux) at (0,-\index) {\index};
   \LinkedList{\list}
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Question:** I have add these few things first thing is to increase the array size and second thing is to make link-list have 3-cell size node and last thing is make a circle over one link-list with some text

Answer (score 3):

I would write the macro in a slightly different way. Your circle can be drawn as an elliptic fit. Notice that there are many more possibilities.

- You could use `shapes.multiparts` for the tableaux.
- You could use `chain`s for the tableaux.
- You could use a `matrix` to place the tableaux. That would make sense in particular if they come with different widths.

However, the purpose of this answer is only to slightly modify what you already had.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcounter{tableau}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit,shapes.geometric}
\tikzset{
node of list/.style = { 
             draw, 
             fill=orange!20, 
             minimum height=6mm, 
             minimum width=6mm,
             %node distance=6mm
   },
link/.style = {
     -stealth,
     shorten >=1pt
     },
array element/.style = {
    draw, fill=white,
    minimum width = 6mm,
    minimum height = 10mm
  }
}


\newcommand{\LinkedList}[2][]{% 
    \stepcounter{tableau}
  \foreach \element [count=\Z,evaluate=\Z as \LastZ using {int(\Z-1)}] in #2 {
    \ifnum\Z=1
     \node[#1,name=tableau-\thetableau-1,node of list] {$\element$};
     \xdef\FitList{(tableau-\thetableau-1)}
    \else
     \node[name=tableau-\thetableau-\Z,right=-\pgflinewidth of
     tableau-\thetableau-\LastZ,node of list] {$\element$};
     \xdef\FitList{(tableau-\thetableau-1) (tableau-\thetableau-\Z)}
    \fi

  } 
  \node[fit=\FitList,inner sep=0pt,name=tableau-\thetableau]{};
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \index/\list in {1/{e,f,~}, 2/{g,h,~}, 3/{~,~,~}} {
   \LinkedList[anchor=north,xshift=\index*3cm,xshift=1cm]{\list}
}
\foreach \index/\list in {1/{a,b,~}, 2/{c,d,~}, 3/{e,f,~}} {
   \LinkedList[yshift=-2cm,xshift=\index*3cm,xshift=1cm]{\list}
}
\foreach \index/\list in {1/{i,j,~}, 2/{~,~,~}, 3/{e,f,~}} {
   \LinkedList[anchor=south,yshift=-4cm,xshift=\index*3cm,xshift=1cm]{\list}
}
\node[fit=(tableau-4) (tableau-6),ellipse,draw,inner sep=2pt,name=elli,
label={[right=5cm,yshift=6mm,align=center,name=elli-label]{Size\\ almost}}]{};
\draw[-latex] (elli-label) to[bend right=30] (elli.north east);

\node[name=array-1,draw,left=2.5cm of tableau-1-1,minimum height=6mm, 
             minimum width=6mm,label={[font=\small\sffamily]180:1}]{};
\foreach \X [count=\Y] in {2,...,8}
{
\ifnum\X=2
\node[name=array-\X,draw,below=-\pgflinewidth of array-\Y,minimum height=6mm, 
             minimum width=6mm,label={[font=\small\sffamily,name=lab-\X]180:\X}]{};
\else            
\ifnum\X=8
\node[name=array-\X,draw,below=-\pgflinewidth of array-\Y,minimum height=6mm, 
             minimum width=6mm,label={[font=\small\sffamily,name=lab-\X]180:$n$}]{};
\else
\node[name=array-\X,draw,below=-\pgflinewidth of array-\Y,minimum height=6mm, 
             minimum width=6mm]{};
\fi
\fi
}            

\foreach \X [count=\Z] in {2,3}
{
\foreach \Y in {0,3,6}
{
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\Start}{\Y+\Z}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\Target}{\Y+\X}
\draw[-latex] (tableau-\Start.east) to[bend left=15] (tableau-\Target.west);
}
}
\foreach \X in {1,4,7}
{
\draw[-latex] (array-\X) to[bend left=15] (tableau-\X.west);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How add links between lists and array?

Comment: @lovw Just add `\foreach \X in {1,4,7}
{
\draw[-latex] (array-\X) to[bend left=15] (tableau-\X.west);
}`

Comment: @lovw OK, added some text...

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned an optional implementation using the `matrix` library, that has many control commands for styles and coordinates for each node in the matrix; also `positioning`, `fit`, `arrows.meta` libraries that allows a slightly exaggerated implementation...

RESULT:
[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=14pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}  
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows.meta, positioning,fit,shapes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        %Environment config
        >={Stealth[inset=0pt,length=6pt]},
        blue,
        thick,
        %Environment Styles
        MyMatrix/.style={
            matrix of nodes,
            font=\scriptsize,
            line width=0.75pt,
            column sep=-0.5pt,
            row sep=-0.5pt,
            text height=9pt,
            text width =12pt,
            text depth =3pt,
            align=center,
            nodes={draw=blue},
            nodes in empty cells
        }
    ]
    % Start Drawing the thing
    \matrix[
        MyMatrix,
        label=270:\sf Array,
        column 1/.style={nodes={draw=none}}
    ] at (0,0) (M1){%Matrix contents
    1   &|[fill=blue!20]|   \\
    2   &   \\
        &   \\
        &|[fill=blue!40]|\\
        &   \\
        &   \\
    n   &|[fill=blue!60]|   \\
    };

    \matrix[
        MyMatrix,
        right=2cm of M1-1-2.east,
        row 1/.style={nodes={fill=blue!10}}
    ](LL1){%Matrix contents
        e   &f  &   &[1cm]g &h  &   &[1cm]  &&\\
    };

    \matrix[
        MyMatrix,
        right=1.5cm of M1-4-2.east,
        row 1/.style={nodes={fill=blue!30}}
    ](LL2){
        a   &b  &   &[1cm]c &d  &   &[1cm]e&f&\\
    };

    \matrix[
        MyMatrix,
        right=1.5cm of M1-7-2.east,
        row 1/.style={nodes={fill=blue!40}},
        row 1 column 3/.style={text width =20pt,}
    ](LL3){
        i   &j  &   &[1cm]      &   &   &[1cm]  &&\\
    };

    %Draw details:
    \draw[loosely dotted] (M1-3-1.north)--(M1-6-1.south);
    \foreach \x [count=\i] in {1,4,7}{
    \draw[->] (M1-\x-2.center)--(LL\i-1-1.west);
    \draw[->] (LL\i-1-3.east)--(LL\i-1-4.west);
    \draw[->] (LL\i-1-6.east)--(LL\i-1-7.west);
    }
    \node[draw,blue,ellipse,inner xsep=-20pt,fit=(LL2)](SELECT1){};
    \draw[<-,blue](SELECT1.5) -- ++(1,0.5) node[align=center,anchor=west,font=\sf]{Size \\ almost};

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1. What I had in mind is to put the tableaux in a matrix. This will be relevant if they have different sizes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I want to add the caption to the image and i want to use the very light blue color in the image . and I one more thing I am trying to change n to $\log \log n$ then it is going inside the arrray cell. How to avoid it.

Comment: If you are going to use a lot of text in mathematical format you can change in the line 13 `matrix of nodes` for `matrix of math nodes` that you can write without using $ $, now `MyMatrix` style defines the length of the text to `text width =12pt`, so it does not it automatically adjusts to the content, so you'll get the `Overfull \ hbox warning` ... so on line 30 just add a new definition for the length of the text `column 1 / .style = {nodes = {draw = none}, text width = 21pt}`

Comment: If you want to put a caption (not relative to the caption package) just add  `\node[fit=(M1)(LL1),label=90:\sf An idle way to put title]{};`.